# Pandas Cell marked as date, dtype=str not working

Tags: python, pandas, excel

The title explains most of my issue. I am trying to read an excel file in python using pandas and I have phone numbers that are being converted to date by mistake, which is causing them to be "outside the limits" and errors the cell data. I have tried using

```
pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx', dtype=str)
```

and

```
pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx', converters={'DID':str}) # Where DID is the phone number column
```

Both cases give the following error for most of the cells in the column:

`/home/flask/venv/myrepo/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py:211: UserWarning: Cell Ixxx is marked as a date but the serial value xxxxxxxxx.0 is outside the limits for dates. The cell will be treated as an error.`

Thank you

Comment: `df= pd.read_excel("xls_test.xlsx",dtype={'Date':'string','Time':'string'})`

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: It’s not just copy paste. In this case ‘Date’ and ‘Time’ are the actual names of the columns in the 'df'. You should use the one that you have in your excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around this issue, I just added quotes around the phone numbers in the excel sheet by creating a new row and using

`=CHAR(34)&A1&CHAR(34)`

to add quotes, then I copied the row over, exported the excel to my server, and I was able to import the numbers and remove the quotes.